# If $v$ is algebraic over $k(u)$ for some $u\in F$ and $v$ is transcendental over $k$, then $u$ is algebraic over $k(v)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

This is seventh question volume 5 hungerford algebra. I know there are some answers on it already and i have the right answer but still two questions are remaining and even my professor got a lil bit confused ! 
First : where are v and u ? We know about u but what about v
Second : what is the relationship between these two fields ? Is one of them an extension of the other one? Or we are discussing on a bigger field which is an extention of both of them ? The solution seemed to somehow use the fact that we r discussing on a bigger field [image]

Comment: Think of $K, u, v$ as all being contained in a larger field $F$.

Comment: Can you say why ? I'm really confused. Why we say K is contained in F ?

Comment: @D_S I really really appreciate if u explain me what is happening here !

Comment: That's just how Hungerford does it all throughout the chapter: $K$ is always a subfield of $F$, and everything takes place inside $F$.  It's possible he didn't say this explicitly, but that's what's going on here and the proof only makes sense with this interpretation.

Comment: I think there is a contradiction in the solution proposed to question 7 if $v$ is algebraic over $K(u)$ than the polynome f should be non zero or $g_{i}(u) =0 \forall i $
means $f$ is zero ? also $v_{i}$ is lineary independent when i is in {1,..,n-1}and n is the degree of the irreducible polynomial $f $ in $k(u)[X]$ such that $f(u)=0 $